# Ehcache throwing NotSerializableException when moving to Spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm upgrading our existing spring boot 1.5 app to Spring boot 2.0. The application utilizes Spring Integration xmls as well.
The Ehcache component is causing issues while trying to to this. While trying to add the response of a GET call to cache, its throwing an exception:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [httpGatewayLookupSize]; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: When configured copyOnRead or copyOnWrite, a Store will only accept Serializable values, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={}, headers={http_requestMethod=GET .....]] with root cause

java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder

With Spring Boot 1.5 it works perfectly fine and the value(XML Response) inserted in the Cache is of type GenericMessage.
Below is the entire stack trace:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.ReadWriteSerializationCopyStrategy.copyForWrite(ReadWriteSerializationCopyStrategy.java:58)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.ReadWriteSerializationCopyStrategy.copyForWrite(ReadWriteSerializationCopyStrategy.java:35)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.CopyStrategyHandler.copyElementForWriteIfNeeded(CopyStrategyHandler.java:84)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.AbstractCopyingCacheStore.put(AbstractCopyingCacheStore.java:78)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.CopyingCacheStore.put(CopyingCacheStore.java:29)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1616)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1542)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1507)
at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.put(EhCacheCache.java:128)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:783)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:400)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:316)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:112)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:227)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:497)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:465)
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:363)
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:255)
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Do i need to explicitly cast the response to make this work?

`CacheInterceptor` implementation that i have:

```
    private MethodInterceptor createGatewayInterceptor(String cacheName) {
    CacheInterceptor interceptor = new CacheInterceptor();
    interceptor.setCacheManager(cacheManager());
    NameMatchCacheOperationSource source = new NameMatchCacheOperationSource();
    CacheableOperation.Builder operationBuilder = new CacheableOperation.Builder();
    operationBuilder.setCacheName(cacheName);
    source.addCacheMethod("handle*Message", Collections.singleton(operationBuilder.build()));
    interceptor.setCacheOperationSources(source);
    interceptor.setKeyGenerator((target, method, params) -> ((Message) params[0]).getHeaders().get(HEADER_CACHEKEY));
    return interceptor;
}
```

DSL cache implementation:

```
    adviceChain.add(eternalCacheAdvice);
    adviceChain.add(genericMessageAdvice);
    handler.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    return handler;

@Bean
public MethodInterceptor cacheAdvice() {
    return createGatewayInterceptor(TWENTY_FOUR_HOUR_CACHE);
}

@Bean
public MethodInterceptor eternalCacheAdvice() {
    return createGatewayInterceptor(ETERNAL_CACHE);
}

@Bean
public MethodInterceptor genericMessageAdvice(){
    return invocation -> ((MessageBuilder<?>) invocation.proceed()).build();
}
@Bean
public MethodInterceptor genericXMLMessageAdvice(){
    return invocation -> ((MessageBuilder<?>) invocation.proceed()).build();
}
```

XML advice chain:

```
        <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="genericXMLMessageAdvice" />
            <ref bean="cacheAdvice" />
        </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some internal optimization many out-of-the-box Spring Integration components now return a `MessageBuilder` before producing replies. This is needed to enrich a target reply message with extra headers.

Looks like the `CacheInterceptor` performs `invocation.proceed()` ad tries to use the result as is for caching.

Consider to add one more `MethodInterceptor` *before* your configured `CacheInterceptor` with a simple implementation like this:

```
invocation -> ((MessageBuilder<?>) invocation.proceed()).build()
```

So, your `CacheInterceptor` will get an expected `GenericMessage<?>` as before.

BTW, we have a PR about caching this n Spring Integration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2105. Feel free to share there your experience, so it may push an out-of-the-box support.

Comment: Thanks @Artem, but how do i chain 2 `MethodInterceptor` in a row? I've added my `CacheInterceptor` implementation to the question above.

Comment: It is not clear by your question what type of configuration you use, but for `XML` it is a ` <int:request-handler-advice-chain>` and beans or their references declared as nested elements are processed in the order you declare them.

Comment: The `@ServiceActivator`, as well as many other Messaging Annotations, has a `adviceChain` which is an array of bean names to be processed in the order they are declared.

Comment: In case of Java DSL, the `ConsumerEndpointSpec` has a `advice(Advice... advice)` configuration option to accept vararg to be processed in the order they are declared here.

Comment: So, either way you need to have to declared `MethodInterceptor`s and have that `CacheInterceptor` down the order, already after an interceptor with an explicit `Message` creation.

Comment: so i have a combination of both DSL and xml configs. I've added these to the question. When i have it this way, the caching for the DSL variant works fine but the xml variant gives the same serializable error. I even tried to swap the order of the advices on the xml config but it still gives the same error.

Comment: What is your `genericXMLMessageAdvice` ?

Comment: Any chances that you can share some simple project to play with?

Comment: Oh, yes! Cache advice must be first in the stack. You really are caching the result of the invocation, so that one must be transformed downstream the call.

Comment: the `genericXMLMessageAdvice` is exactly same as the `genericMessageAdvice`. I've added that too here. I tried making the `cacheAdvice` as the first in the stack but i still get the same serialization error.

Comment: Yeah... we need a sample to play with. Something maybe be missed. Are you sure that you supply a new advice everywhere you have a caching one?

Comment: yeah so thats one thing i need to do and check...currently we have 20 something xmls that all use the cacheConfig. I just changed one of these xmls and tried to test that particular call and its failing. I'll try to change all the xmls (which i anyway wud be doing) and add this additional advice on each of these and then test.

Comment: Yep, thats what it was....the additional advice was needed at all places where the cacheAdvice was being called. Thanks @Artem!!